# file exists but I cannot open it using php

Tags: php, linux, apache, file

I can open and write in file using vim command but i cant open it using PHP

```
$myFile = "v.txt"; 
if(!file_exists($myFile)){
    print 'File not found';
}else if(!$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+')){
    print 'Can\'t open file \n';}.
else{  
    print 'Success open file';
}
```

Comment: I am using my own linux server

Comment: maybe the file needs or requires a root permission or some sort of privilege for some user to modify or read the file?

Comment: Be sure that file has permisions to write for `www-data` user

Comment: check logs for reason and make sure E_WARNING is reported: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-errors

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
ls -l
```

on the directory that contains the file. Make sure the user that's running your web server has access read rights to the file